# Check if a general nth degree diophantine equation has solutions

Tags: diophantine-equations

How do I check if a general nth degree diophantine equation has integer solutions or any solutions? Is there a general algorithm for this?

I have seen answers on the internet using congruence modulo but I simply don't get why or how they find the number to which modulo is taken. And how they conclude that there are solutions or not. A generalized elaboration would help immensely.

Comment: How many variables are you considering?

Comment: Reducing a Diophantine equation modulo something can only rule out a class of integers as solutions (to either rule out all integers, or narrow down the search). It can never, by its own, show that there _are_ solutions.

Comment: @Arthur Ok thanks for clearing that bit up. Now how would i go about checking if there are no solutions for diophantine equations of the nth degree, for say two variables $x,y$

Comment: There is a result that says it is impossible don't remember who or what it is.

Comment: There isn't any such algorithm. Even the elliptic curve case is already very hard. But that's just the cubic case!

Comment: @Toni are you thinking of hilbert's 10th problem?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing at.